# Unable to pull out resetSet for insert within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been looking online for a few days to find a solution and 
I may be asking the wrong questions.

I have the following stored proc which on insertion of a row to a db I want to get back the output int (@outResult). This is the stored proc :

```
USE [DB1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[storedProc1]    Script Date: 04/12/2016 10:16:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedProc1]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @inParam nvarchar(max),
    @outResult int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT ID
        FROM dbo.table1
        WHERE Field1 = @inParam 
    )
    Insert into [DB1].[dbo].[table1] 
    (
    Field1
    )
    Values (
    @inParam 
    )

    SET @outResult = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

When I run the following SQL and try to retrieve the resultSet :

```
SELECT * FROM (EXEC storedProc1 'field1')
```

I get the following error:
**"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'"**

Maybe I am approaching this problem wrong from the first place?
I will continue to look into this and provide a solution if I find one.Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use a table-valued function instead of a stored procedure if you want to reference it in a select. Note that this might not be the actual solution to your problem, because it looks like you just want to know how to use an `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I just want to access the out parameter, so maybe my select is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of the output parameter you need to supply the call to the SP with an output argument. You do that by specifying the OUTPUT option on the second parameter.

```
 DECLARE @returned_ID INT; 
 EXEC storedProc1 @inParam = 'field1', 
                  @outResult = @returned_ID OUTPUT

 SELECT @returned_ID
```

Comment: Perfect! That's it! Thank you from tearing my hair out! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve just the out parameter, then You can read it as :

```
    DECLARE @output int
    EXEC storedProc1 'field1',@output OUTPUT 
    SELECT @output
```